# Get current authenticated user's email in aws-amplify v6

Tags: aws-amplify

The `getCurrentUser` function imported from `aws-amplify/auth` only gives me **username, userId, signInDetails**. I want the current user's **email**.

I also tried with `fetchAuthSession` but I couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `fetchUserAttributes` function. This returns an object containing the user's attributes.

[Here](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/auth-migration-guide/#authuserattributes) are the docs for migrating v5 to v6 that discuss this function.

Answer (score 1):

## Getting Attributes of a user in AWS Amplify

You can use `fetchUserAttributes` function imported from `@aws-amplify/auth` to get `userAttributes` of current logged in user.

### Here is a sample code

The following code prints user's email when button is clicked. You can find it's documentation in [Amplify Auth -> Retrieve user attributes](https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/manage-user-profile/#retrieve-user-attributes).

```
import { fetchUserAttributes } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import React from 'react';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {

  // Function to print access token and id token
  const printUserAttributes = async () => {
    try {
      const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
      console.log('Email:', userAttributes.email);
    }
    catch (e) { console.log(e); }
  };

  return (
    <Authenticator hideSignUp loginMechanisms={['username']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
          <button onClick={printUserAttributes}>Print Attributes</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

`fetchAuthSession` can also be used to get Email of a user but the recommended way is to use `fetchUserAttributes`. If you are curious to know how to get this with `fetchAuthSession`, You can find user's email in `session.tokens.idToken.payload.email`.

I have answered a similar question which uses `fetchAuthSession` here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77731602/11475585