# How to get user access token in AWS Amplify UI Authenticator

Tags: aws-amplify

I am using **Authenticator** and **useAuthenticator** from **@aws-amplify/ui-react**
Upon successful login is there a way to get the access token? When i output the user attribute from useAuthenticator access token is not included.
Also what function I can use to refresh the token.

```
import { Authenticator, useAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const App = () => {
    const { user, signOut } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.user]);

    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {
        Cognito: {
          userPoolClientId: <client id>,
          userPoolId: <user pool id>,
 
        },
      },
    });

    return  (
      <Authenticator
        hideSignUp={true}
        components={components}
        loginMechanisms={["username"]}
      >
        {() => {}}
      </Authenticator>
     );

}
```

Comment: Updated description with code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Getting Access Token and ID Token of a user when using Amplify UI Authenticator

You can use `fetchAuthSession` function imported from `@aws-amplify/auth` to get `accessToken` and `idToken` of current logged in user.

### Here is a sample code

The following code prints the token when Print Tokens button is clicked. This function will also provide you all user attributes in the payload. You can find it's documentation in [Amplify Auth Accessing credentials](https://docs.amplify.aws/android/build-a-backend/auth/accessing-credentials/).

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import React from 'react';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {

  // Function to print access token and id token
  const printAccessTokenAndIdToken = async () => {
    try {
      const session = await fetchAuthSession();   // Fetch the authentication session
      console.log('Access Token:', session.tokens.accessToken.toString());
      console.log('ID Token:', session.tokens.idToken.toString());
    }
    catch (e) { console.log(e); }
  };

  return (
    <Authenticator hideSignUp loginMechanisms={['username']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
          <button onClick={printAccessTokenAndIdToken}>Print Tokens</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

##### If You are trying to fetch the token automatically without a user action, you might have to consider using `Hub` imported from `aws-amplify/utils`

### Here is a sample code using Amplify Hub

The following uses Amplify Hub to start listening to auth related events and upon `signedIn` calls `fetchAuthSession` function to print the token. You can find it's documentation in [Amplify Hub Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/utilities/hub/).

```
import { fetchAuthSession } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Hub } from 'aws-amplify/utils';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe to auth events
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      console.log('A new auth event has happened: ', event);
      switch (event) {
        case 'signedIn':
          console.log('user signed in');
          printAccessTokenAndIdToken();
          break;
        case 'signedOut':
          console.log('user signed out');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // Function to print access token and id token
  const printAccessTokenAndIdToken = async () => {
    try {
      const session = await fetchAuthSession();   // Fetch the authentication session
      console.log('Access Token:', session.tokens.accessToken.toString());
      console.log('ID Token:', session.tokens.idToken.toString());
    }
    catch (e) { console.log(e); }
  };

  return (
    <Authenticator hideSignUp loginMechanisms={['username']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I follow the 1st option but now i am getting undefined for access token and id token. I check the network tab and API returns access token. Did i miss additional configuration to return the tokens from fetchAuthSession? I am using Amplify v6.

Comment: Can you please try `fetchUserAttributes` in place of fetchAuthSession and check if it returns user attributes ?. 

More on this here https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/manage-user-profile/#retrieve-user-attributes.

Comment: Hi its working now after updating latest version of aws-amplify to v 6.0.9. thanks