# How to get and display name and email from fetchUserAttributes() in basic AWS Amplify React JS webapp

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I have the same issue as listed in the link below, although I am struggling to display the user email as a simple text string in my webapp (in the return output):

[get-current-authenticated-users-email-in-aws-amplify-v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77718195/get-current-authenticated-users-email-in-aws-amplify-v6/)

Approximately two months ago (Dec 2023) AWS Amplify changed functions such as AUTH which broke my former coding to display current user name and email.  I am new to javascript and React so really need basic beginner examples of how the new changes to AWS Amplify React Javascript V6 work (migrating from V5).  The current documentation is dreadful (for a beginner).  A simple entire App.js example to display user name and user email (a simple Hello world) is required.

I found some information here too, and it is very helpful but I'm learning javascript and still can't display user email (no errors or warnings, but nothing appears).  [(imported as 'Auth') was not found in 'aws-amplify'](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12591)

The solution shown below that was provided by @Abiram does successfully show the user's email in the Console, but I'm not sure how to display the email in my webapp (instead of the console).

I'm basically building a chat app and want to include the username, user email, and current datetime in every chat message.

The code below works, but instead of 'userAttributes.email' print to Console I want to return/output (display on my webapp) into a textbox.

```
import { fetchUserAttributes } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import React from 'react';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

export default function App() {

  // Function to print access token and id token
  const printUserAttributes = async () => {
    try {
      const userAttributes = await fetchUserAttributes();
      console.log('Email:', userAttributes.email);
    }
    catch (e) { console.log(e); }
  };

  return (
    <Authenticator hideSignUp loginMechanisms={['username']}>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
          <button onClick={printUserAttributes}>Print Attributes</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

I can display user email to console, but learning javascript and not sure how to display in return/output.